# MySQL insert stmt wont loop in file upload foreach loop

Tags: php

The code uploads the files and is supposed to submit the file path to the database so I can use the file paths elsewhere.

All the files upload fine in the loop, but for some reason, after it successfully submits the first MySQL stmt insert, it somehow bypasses the inserts that come after when it goes through the loop again, to upload the next file in the `$_FILES[]` superglobal

Here is the markup for the form

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'includes/functions.php';
drawHeader();


echo'
  <div class="main_content_container">
';

if ( isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {

  $amz_numb = $_GET['amz_numb'];

  echo'
    <form action="http://Localhost/Tierrashop.ca/includes/upload.php"
      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      Send these files

      <input name="amz_numb" type="hidden"
      value="'. $amz_numb .'"/><br />

      <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />
      <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />

      <button type="file">Upload Files</button>
    </form>

    <a href="http://localhost/Tierrashop.ca/content_upload.php">
    <button>Go back to product details... </button></a>
  ';



} else {
  echo '';
}

//close of main content div
echo '</div>';

drawFooter();
?>
```

PHP file that launches upon form submission

```
<?php

include 'config.php';
if (isset($_POST['amz_numb'])) {
    $uploadlocation = "../product_images/";

    $amz_numb = $_POST['amz_numb'];

    // Count total files
    $countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

    // Looping all files
    for ($i = 0; $i < $countfiles; $i++) {
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

        // Upload file
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadlocation . $filename);
        $directory_location = $uploadlocation . basename($filename);
        chmod($directory_location, 0644);

        //insert amz numb and path into db
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO images ( amz_product_code, filepath )
    VALUES (?,?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $amz_numb, $directory_location);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this please:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php

The user contributed note might be helpful for your case:

"if you are repeating an statement in an loop using bind_param and so on inside it for a larger operation. i thougt id would be good to clean it with stmt->close. but it broke always with an error after aprox. 250 operations . As i tried it with  stmt->reset it worked for me."

This might be the better option: https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.reset.php

Or - much better - use PDO!

UPDATE: More on PDO

If you don't know how to use the more modern standard "PDO" (if I recall it correctly it stands for "PHP Data Objects") this should be really helpful. I used this myself to make my own database handler.
https://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/

The only caveat: The link above is a bit US centric. If you use it like that you will be in trouble if you support other languages in addition to English(US).

In //Define Configuration you should add:

```
define("DB_CHARSET",        "utf8mb4");
```

Then in the database class itself you should add:

```
private $charset = DB_CHARSET;
```

"Set DSN" should consequently be modified like this:

```
 $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset=' . $this->charset;
```

Apart from these minor changes the example is still very useful.

Comment: And underlined for the final sentence on this answer `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Yaaaaa, none of that resetting stuff helped.

Figured out you don't have to keep preparing the statement, however not sure if that's what was stopping it.

I had it uploading the file, than was preparing the stmt to then execute.

In the php.ini file I had:
max_file_uploads = 3, which explained why only three files were getting inserted and locking up the script in the loop.

Also I changed post_max_size = 150mb thinking that this allows all those files to be stored in the tmp_name key in the $_FILES superglobal